# Стороннее консольное приложение запускает дочернее, как из своего приложения отобразить дочернее "внука"?

Tags: c++, winapi, radstudio, ipc

Мое приложение запускает дочернее посредством `CreateProcess`, скрытое в режиме `SW_HIDE`, с перенаправлением ввода/вывода.

Дочернее, соответственно, запускает свое дочернее (для моего получается уже "внук"), но оба они остаются скрытыми. Есть ли возможность из моего приложения оставить скрытым только дочернее, а "внука" отобразить?

Добавлю - вызываемое приложение ниразу не мое. И в документированных опциях вызова того приложения возможно только отключить всплывание потомка (для моего - соответственно - "внука")

Comment: Можно передавать создаваемому процессу аргумент командной строки: отображать ли окно создаваемого дочернего процесса. В коде сделать соответствующую обработку этого аргумента.

Comment: А внук оконный или консольный?

Answer (score 1):

"Системного" способа нет, нужно вручную в дочернем процессе явно флаги выставлять для внучатого процесса.

Comment: а MSDN говорит что есть такая ф-ия FindWindow - только ума не приложу как это может помочь (((

Answer (score 1):

При помощи `WMI` (выполнив запрос WQL) можно выудить все дочерние процессы вашего дочернего процесса, а потом заслать ему `ShowWindow`.

Доступ к WMI можно получить посредством COM API.